# encoding issue, database saving chars not in output

Tags: php, mysql, regex, rich-text-editor

Okay I have an RTE set up (snapeditor)

When I enter the text `Hello World!`

my `view source` within the editor of text is

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

my `echo` immediately before saving to database is (output to a textarea box)

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

my database stores

```
 <p>ï»¿1Hello World!</p>
```

to remove the extra bit I have tried the following (along with some other attempted regex/replace methods)

```
$var['note'] = preg_replace("/&#\\d+;/", "", $var['note']);
$var['note'] = preg_replace("/\bï»¿1\b/", "", $var['note']);
$blockChars = array('ï', '»', '¿');
$var['note'] = str_replace($blockChars, '', $var['note']);
```

most recently tried (immediately after insert, and getting the insert id)

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET note = REPLACE(note, 'ï»¿', '') WHERE id = ?";
```

I have tried changing database encoding to `latin` and `utf-8`

I can't for the life of me figure out how to stop the database from storing the extra chars... help is appreciated

Comment: Try configuring the DB encoding to UTF8 *without* BOM.

Comment: mysqli::set_charset('utf-8'); maybe helps

Comment: tried `$this->db->set_charset('utf-8');` before the prepare, did not change result

Comment: What about trimming the string with `$var['note'] = preg_replace("~^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$~", "", $var['note']);`? (maybe with `u` option)

Comment: maybe useful: [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases - or -The things we do to store U+01F4A9 PILE OF POO (Alternate title)](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

Comment: Does SnapEditor have a way to turn off BOM?

Comment: @stribizhev doing this, entered a null value in my db...`$var['note'] = preg_replace("~^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$~", "", $var['note']);`

Comment: @RyanVincent changing to utf8mb4_general_ci turned the 3 char string into a `?`

Comment: @RickJames not that I am aware of